# Class constructor Construct cannot be invoked without 'new' - aws cdk

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I have an NPM library here that will be used across multiple CDK apps and AWS accounts

```
export class FrontendConstruct extends Construct {
  constructor(parent: Construct, id: string, props: FrontendConstructProps) {
    super(parent, id);

//creating s3 bucket etc
//create cloudfront cdn
```

Here is my stack on the cdk app using it

```
import * as ssFE from '@customnpmlibrary/cdk-ss-fe'

export interface stFrontendStackProps extends cdk.StackProps {
  /**
   * The domain name for the site to use
   */
  readonly domainName: string;
  /**
 * Location of FE code to deploy
 */
  readonly deploymentSource: string;
}

export class stFrontendStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props: stFrontendStackProps) {
    super(scope, id,props);

    new ssFE.FrontendConstruct 
      (this, 'stfeStack', {
      domainname: props.domainName,
      deploymentSource: props.deploymentSource
    });
  
  }
}
```

and creating the app

```
import { stFrontendStack } from '../lib/st-frontend-stack';

const app = new cdk.App();

new stFrontendStack(app, 'stFrontend-DEV', {
  env: {
    account: '1234',
    region: 'us-east-1'
  },
  domainName: 'url.url.com',
  deploymentSource:'../dist/stfe'
});
```

when I go to deploy it I get this: during cdk synth

```
Class constructor Construct cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

Any thoughts or help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is with your ECMAScript version. This can be fixed by using ES2018 in your `tsconfig.json` as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target":"ES2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2018"],
    ... any other options ...
  }
}
```

Also, I ran into an issue when running `tsc` with parameters. You need to make sure that `tsc` is picking up the `tsconfig.json` properly. For me, removing parameters from `tsc` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to happen with me when my dependencies are not up to date. I will usually nuke my node_modules/ (`rm -rf node_modules`) and do an `npm install` again.